# jquery datetimepicker not showing nice formatting box around the calendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have been working with this for hours. It would appear that the CSS is not working, but I cant figure out why.  I have included it in the bundles,

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
                        "~/Scripts/Scott.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
```

and I have rendered it in the _layout page.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

yet when I run the program and click on the datetime field, it looks like this:
[image]

Is it a setting or do I have something out of order?
Thanks for the help.
-Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was missing jquery-ui.css.  Once I added this css file it all appears as normal.  Somehow, when I added jQuery.UI.Combined 1.12.1 it did not add the css file too.